# does pyspark broadcast function make deepcopy of variable?

Tags: python, pyspark

Suppose, I have a variable which is a dict of dicts.

```
h = {1: {2:3}, 5: {6: 7}}
```

I want to broadcast it to mappers in pyspark. Is it enough to broadcast only `h` like this

```
h0 = sc.broadcast(h)
```

and then use it as a broadcasted var: `h0.value[5][6]`

OR should I broadcast all of its values like this:

```
h0 = {k: sc.broadcast(v) for k, v in h.iteritems()}
...
def mapper():
    inner_h = {k, v for k, v in h0.iteritems()}
    inner_h[5].value[6]
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use it for collections

```
sc.broadcast(h) and  h.value
```

Here is a useful [link](http://www.learn4master.com/big-data/spark/pyspark-broadcast-variable-example) with some examples